# Как сделать команду рассылки на discord.js v13.6.0

Tags: discord, discord.py

вот эта команда на питоне

```
@bot.command()
async def broadcast(ctx, *, msg):
    for server in bot.servers:
        for channel in server.channels:
            try:
                await bot.send_message(channel, msg)
            except Exception:
                continue
            else:
                break
```

мне надо знать, как написать это на js

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Точно также как на python, только с использованием синтаксиса и особенностей js. В чем конкретно вопрос-то? Не знаете как организовать цикл `for` на js? Как отправить сообщение? Если вам просто нужен готовый код — заходите на любой фриланс сайт с запросом "Переписать код с Python на JS" и вам за 500р все сделают в лучшем виде. Здесь стоит переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы он был сфокусирован на одной конкретной проблеме.